# Google-Chart Bar Animation

Tags: javascript, cordova, charts, google-visualization

Which property of google chart adds the Animation in column chart from top to bottom ?

By Adding

```
animation: {duration: 10000, easing: 'out',}
```

in option is enough or we need to add something else also for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is enought add

```
animation: {
            duration: 1000
        }
```

have a look in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/bwULk/) example that I have found

refer [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation) page for documentation about animation property

example

```
function init() {
    var options = {
      width: 400,
      height: 240,
      animation:{
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out'
      },
      vAxis: {minValue:0, maxValue:1000}
    };
```

Comment: var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        animation: {duration: 100000},
        chartArea: {width: '80%'}, 
        legend : { position:"bottom"},
       hAxis: {title: 'key Indicator', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize:5}}
      };
In Above code I am not able to animate my bars

Comment: I've tried your options inside my example and the animation works. Try to put your code in a not working example and I'll try to make it work

Comment: What this line of code do in your referenced example link ?
    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });

Comment: it is the function where the chart is drawed. when the chart is ready it draw the chart and delete the listener

Comment: Do I need to add this because i didnt add this line of code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the last comma `,`.

Try with this:

```
animation: {duration: 10000, easing: 'out'}
```